# Get hour range between each day

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, aggregate

I have a pandas dataframe containing timestamps. And I would like to know the hours between the first entry of the day and the last one, this is what I have:

```
time      | Hour
----------|---------
2010-01-01| 06:44:00 
2010-01-01| 06:28:00
2010-01-01| 14:47:00
2010-01-02| 06:44:00
2010-01-02| 06:28:00
2010-01-02| 15:57:00
```

this is what I want

```
---------------------
Day        | Hours
-----------|---------
2010-01-01 | 08:03:00
2010-01-02 | 09:13:00
```

Comment: How did you arrive at 08:03:00 for your output example? Seems to me the difference is only 16 minutes as illustrated in my answer.

Comment: You should really post the code, that is generating the outputs you have posted in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
# First I recreate a similar dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"day": ["2010-01-01", "2010-01-01","2010-01-02","2010-01-02", "2010-01-02"],
                   "hour": pd.date_range("2010-01-01 06:44:00", freq="h", periods=5)})
df.hour = df.hour.dt.time
```

My df is :

```
         day      hour
0  2010-01-01  06:44:00
1  2010-01-01  07:44:00
2  2010-01-02  08:44:00
3  2010-01-02  09:44:00
4  2010-01-02  10:44:00
```

To obtain time difference between first and last hour I `groupby` day, get the first and last values and then substract them:

```
df = df.sort_values(["day", "hour"])
df["hour"] = pd.to_datetime(df["day"] + " " + df["hour"].astype("str"))
df = df.groupby("day").hour.agg(["first", "last"])
df = df["last"] - df["first"]
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'hours'})
```

And the result is :

```
         day    hours
0  2010-01-01 01:00:00
1  2010-01-02 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use resample and find the difference between the min and max values for each day. Before reading in your example data, I removed the "Hour" column name, so that there was just one column named "Time."

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"[ ]{2,}").set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']))

df_rs_min = df.resample('D').agg('min')

df_rs_max = df.resample('D').agg('max')

merged_df = df_rs_max.merge(df_rs_min, left_on=df_rs_max.index, right_on=df_rs_min.index)

merged_df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['time_x']) - pd.to_datetime(merged_df['time_y'])

merged_df = merged_df[['key_0', 'diff']]

merged_df.rename(columns={'key_0': 'day', 'diff':'hours' }, inplace=True)

print(merged_df)

day hours
0   2010-01-01  00:16:00
1   2010-01-02  09:29:00
```